# how can i display when i enter ID in URL like this (/student/:1) according to the array, All the details want to display according to the ID?

Tags: javascript, node.js

here is the student_details.JSON file

```
{
    "Students" : [
        {"ID" : "1" ,
         "Name" : "janaka",
         "Grade" : "A"
        },
        {"ID" : "2" ,
         "Name" : "Darshana",
         "Grade" : "B"
        },
        ]}
```

### here is the js file

- how can i display when i enter ID in URL (/student/:1) according to the array, All the details according to the ID?

  `var express = require('express');
      var app = express();
      var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
      var fs = require('fs');`

---

### respond to page

```
app.get('/students/:id',function(req ,res){

    console.log('got a get request from homepage');
    fs.readFile( __dirname + "/" + "Students_details.json", 'utf8',function(err,data){

        var content = JSON.parse(data);

        var studentsArray = content.Students;

        **//how to write code here**

       res.send(req.params.id);
    });

})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply get student data from array by `Id` passed in query string.

```
app.get('/students/:id',function(req ,res){

    console.log('got a get request from homepage');
    fs.readFile( __dirname + "/" + "Students_details.json", 'utf8',function(err,data){

        var content = JSON.parse(data);
        var studentsArray = content.Students;

        var studentId = req.query.id;

        var student = studentsArray.find(st => {
            return st.ID == studentId;
        });

        // student variable is you information about student with given student id.

        res.send(student);
    });

})
```